# How do I make a Bitcoin "memory wallet" (or paper wallet without paper)?

Tags: wallet, data-security, coldstorage, paper-wallet

I'd like to see a video tutorial that explains in detail how to make a paper wallet without paper, AKA, a "memory wallet" -- thx.

Comment: this is a dangerous thing to do because if you forget, you will loose your bitcoins forever

Comment: Related question: [How to save bitcoins as paper](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/how-to-save-bitcoins-as-paper/1082)

Answer (score 1):

step 1 - memorize all the private keys that would otherwise be stored in some sort of [wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet) file

step 2 - there is no step 2

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use **http://brainwallet.org** to generate a so-called "Memory Wallet". ***Do not use the live website, download the sourcecode from github.***

How this works is you select a phrase, like "Correct Horse Battery Staple", and that phrase will consistently compute to a keypair you can use to store and later retrieve bitcoins.

BE EXTREMELY CAREFUL, or maybe don't do this at all. There are untold numbers of robots perpetually checking the blockchain for any conceivable passphrase. If your passphrase is not EXTREMELY strong, any coins you put in there will likely be swiped in a matter of hours, if not minutes.

See: http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1ndsxi/a_test_of_brainwallet_passphrases/

If you really want to make a brain wallet, I recommend something absolutely impossible to brute force, like

*my favorite superhero, childhood address, my social security number*

giving you

Captain Underpants, 112 Elm Street, Oakland, CA, 555-1212-555

Answer (score 0):

This is most secure way to place your Bitcoins in cold storage.

This quick [Video Tutorial](http://youtu.be/we3VgdWCYEI) explains how to make 
a Dr. Evil Paper Wallet or Bitcoin "Brain Wallet."

Get the ZIP file for Dr Evil Paper Wallet Generator @GitHub
https://github.com/obesityspray/Dr.-Evil-Paper-Wallet

Answer (score 0):

Well, the brain wallet is essentially the mnemonic.

You can try using the [BIP 39](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) tool. But keep in mind to save the code from [Github](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39) and run it while Offline. Preferrably in a Tails OS or some disposable system/hardware (one can never be too paranoid).

After that, just keep those words in your head. When you need to interact with the wallet you download some standard wallet and while on setup, hit "recover" and insert the mnemonic that is in your brain.

Comment: % echo -n "Your Crrrappy Hi Entoppi 8rain 5ollet Praize" | bx [base16-encode](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-base16-encode) | bx [sha256](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-sha256) | cut -c 1-64 | bx [mnemonic-new](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-mnemonic-new)
```captain license mother demise merge must soldier good exit very wheat prefer useful congress riot airport dune ghost purpose sausage hospital myth hole federal```,  and don't forget to use a BIP 39 passphrase to complement the your unique quoted echo string.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without the paper is using:

**Memory Paper Wallet: https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet**

It's a fork of the original warp wallet code base: https://github.com/keybase/warpwallet with added features:

- Generate multiple crypto addresses besides Bitcoin.
- Printable and easily use for gifting occasions.
- Ability to split a private key using shamir secret sharing.