# How to download wallet from coinbase

Tags: wallet, coinbase-transaction

I got some newbie questions;

I bought some bitcoin on Coinbase.

I want to download the wallet, I'll probably put it on a USB then throw it in the safe. Could someone advise how I can download the wallet?

Once downloaded is it still also mirrored on coinbase?

Comment: related: [How to save bitcoins as paper?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1080/5406)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do that.. it's another type of wallet

https://community.coinbase.com/t/saving-all-bitcoins-on-usb-stick-so-they-are-safe-from-usg-confiscation/233/5 <-- there are some info as well..

Comment: You must register in another place to get this type of wallet.. + coinbase isn't that secure wallet if you search for security ;)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.